# How to model partial wavefunction collapse when part of a wavefunction hits a barrier?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

This code models a complex Gaussian wavefunction expanding from the origin, part of which hits a barrier at x=10, Abs[y]<15. The code shows the wavefunction reflecting off the barrier, which is incorrect. The part of the wavefunction that hits the barrier and the walls of the box should vanish (go to zero) upon hitting the barrier and the walls of the box, while the rest of the wavefunction should continue expanding. This is because the barrier and wall are lined with perfectly efficient detectors, and a non-measurement by these detectors will collapse the wavefunction to zero at the barrier and walls. Here are the barrier and walls:

[image: potential]
Here is the wavefunction interacting with the barrier (barrier and walls not shown):

[image: wavefunction]

```
Clear[psi, x, y, t, v, psins, psin];
psi[x_, y_, t_] := (2/\[Pi])^(1/2) 1/(I t + 2) Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/(2 I t + 4))];
v[x_, y_] := 20 (1 - HeavisidePi[x/120, y/120] + HeavisidePi[x/3 - 3, y/30]);
psins = NDSolveValue[{I D[psin[x, y, t], {t, 1}] + 
  1/2 Laplacian[psin[x, y, t], {x, y}] - v[x, y]*psin[x, y, t] == 
 0, psin[x, y, 0] == psi[x, y, 0], psin[-50, y, t] == 0, 
psin[50, y, t] == 0, psin[x, -50, t] == 0, psin[x, 50, t] == 0}, psin, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, {t, 0, 15}, MaxStepSize -> 1];
ListAnimate[Table[Plot3D[Re[psins[x, y, t]], {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 0.4}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1], {t, 0, 15}], AnimationRate -> 1]
```

Comment: Why should it go to zero at the barrier? For an infinite potential height, yes, but for a barrier with finite width and height, won't there be a small but non-zero amplitude for tunneling?

Comment: @jdp I apologize for omitting some details. The barrier is lined with perfectly efficient detectors. The wavefunction will either trigger one of these detectors, causing the wavefunction to vanish everywhere else, or the wavefunction will not trigger any of these detectors, implying any part of the wavefunction touching the barrier dropped to zero. This is an "interaction-free measurement," also known as a "Renninger negative-result measurement." See Wikipedia for more details.

Comment: I see. But then the question is, how is this information incorporated into your calculation? I notice that you're setting psin to 0 at x,y = +/- 50. Is that what you mean by barrier? I assumed you meant the regions where the potential rose, similar to a square well. But if you meant +/-50, that's only going to constrain the wave function at a point - not necessarily at all points beyond 50.

Comment: @jdp The barrier of interest is defined by the potential v[x,y].  It is a wall at x=10 & y=+/-15 of height 20. To see it: 'Plot3D[v[x, y], {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, Exclusions -> None]'

Comment: One possibility is to add a call to WhenEvent[event,action] to the solver. The measurement process isn't described by the evolution equation, so trying to simulate it via the equation and initial/boundary conditions may not prove effective. WhenEvent can monitor the variables in NDSolve each time step, and effect a more or less arbitrary action, including a discontinuous change in the function's behavior, much like wave function collapse. This might be a better way to simulate the detector behavior, though it may slow the simulation down - possibly a lot.

Comment: ...So your event would be reaching the barrier, and your action would be to zero out the function (and any derivatives if necessary).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: @jdp I tried 'WhenEvent[Re[psin[10, y, t]] > 0.01, psin[x, y, t] -> 0]' but it didn't work.

Comment: I'll try to take a look tomorrow morning. You might try adding print statements (there are before/after examples in the documentation under Scope/Actions) to see if the code is having any effect. Or just have it terminate evaluation, to see if the condition is triggering, etc.

Comment: I just had time for a quick look. If I replace psin[]->0 with "StopIntegration", or Print[something], etc., I get error messages and a stack trace. If I use something like WhenEvent[Mod[t,2],Print["event"]], no errors. I don't think it likes the condition. Maybe becauae you're using [10,y,t], and it doesn't like the y? Most of the examples are 1d, so maybe 2d requires some finesse. Or an additional predicate of some sort. We probably should either move this to chat or delete some of the older comments, since SE keeps putting up warning messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145762/discussion-between-michael-b-heaney-and-jdp).

Answer (score 5):

This problem can be solved with FEM by expanding $psin=u+iv$ and adding Dirichlet type conditions as follows

```
reg = RegionDifference[
  ImplicitRegion[-50 <= x <= 50 && -50 <= y <= 50, {x, y}], 
  ImplicitRegion[
   Abs[x/3 - 3] <= 1/2 && Abs[y/30] <= 1/2, {x, y}]];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/2];

psi[x_, y_, 
  t_] := (2/\[Pi])^(1/2) 1/(I t + 
     2) Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/(2 I t + 4))]; eq = {D[
     u[x, y, t], {t, 1}] + 1/2 Laplacian[v[x, y, t], {x, y}] == 
   0, -D[v[x, y, t], {t, 1}] + 1/2 Laplacian[u[x, y, t], {x, y}] == 
   0}; ic = {u[x, y, 0] == psi[x, y, 0], 
  v[x, y, 0] == 
   0}; bc = {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, t] == 0, v[x, y, t] == 0}, 
   True]};
sol = NDSolve[Join[eq, ic, bc], {u, v}, 
  Element[{x, y}, mesh], {t, 0, 20}];
```

Visualization

```
Table[Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y, t] /. sol[[1]]], Element[{x, y}, reg], 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> Hue, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, Boxed -> False, PlotTheme -> "Marketing"], {t, 0, 
  20, 5}]

Table[DensityPlot[Evaluate[u[x, y, t] /. sol[[1]]], 
  Element[{x, y}, reg], PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, Frame -> False], {t, 0, 20, 
  5}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank you for your attempted solution. However, the plots show at least some of the wavefunction being reflected by the barrier. Also, running the code out to t=40 shows the wavefunction being reflected by the walls of the potential well.

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney It means that you are not right about nonreflecting conditions in the form of  "go to zero". :)

Comment: Apologies, I see the misunderstanding. By "go to zero" I meant disappeared discontinuously once the wave touched the barrier, not that the wave went continuously to zero when it approached the barrier.

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney But in this solution wave approaches barrier even at `t=0`. Maybe wavefunction collapses at special condition dependent on detector?   Also it is nor clear why one part collapsing while another part should continue expanding.

Comment: Any part of the wavefunction that touches the barrier or walls should instantaneously drop to zero upon touching the barrier or walls, while any part of the wavefunction that is not touching the barrier or walls should continue to propagate freely. This is dictated by the collapse postulate of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney In our solution with Mathematica FEM we use `bc = {DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, t] == 0, v[x, y, t] == 0}, True]}` to describe your words  "Any part of the wavefunction that touches the barrier or walls should instantaneously drop to zero upon touching the barrier or walls" .

Comment: I think the OP's point is that although the wave function is 0 at and beyond the boundary, there is still a reflection at the boundary propagating to the left.

Comment: @jdp The question is very good, but it looks like many particles problem, so that we need to add some discrete source of particles.